# File upload error in Opencart in Download Module

Tags: opencart

I am working on opencart theme. I have installed the opencart latest 2.0 and haveing some issue with admin side in download modules. File type zip and .rar is not supported in that. I have checked in settngs tabs in server there is mimetype already addeed zip and rar. i want to slove this. Can any one has some idea how to slove this ?.

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking about. What has a theme development in common with file download in administration? BTW, If you find a way how to *slove* it, let me know. This *slovation* has to be a damn new thing! Nor google knows about it. But I could have some ideas what this *slovation* thing might be... Hmmm....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencart 2.0 is missing some mime types for zip. You'll need to add these too, if you want support in all browsers:

```
application/x-zip
application/zip-compressed
application/x-zip-compressed
application/x-compress
application/octet-stream
```

I'm unsure about rar. I thought there wasn't an issue. I'd suggest adding the above and if you still have issues then post back and I'll see what else you might need.